# MySQL Query to Fetch Latest Posts w.r.t created date and replied date

Tags: php, mysql

I hope all of you are in good health.

I am working on a project like a social website. I have two tables named: **posts** and **post_replies**.

I want to show the **Updated Posts**. **Updated Posts** here means the posts that are created recently or replied recently using the above mentioned two tables.

I am showing the structure of both tables below:

**Table: posts**

id, title, added_on

**Table: post_replies**

id, post_id, comment, added_on

(post_id is foreign key of id in posts)

So ....

To fetch the recently created posts I have written the below query:

```
SELECT id, title FROM posts ORDER BY added_on DESC
```

To fetch the recently replied posts I have written the below query:

```
SELECT id, comment FROM post_replies GROUP BY post_id ORDER BY added_on DESC
```

My question is that how can i combine both the above queries to fetch the latest posts based on creation date and the datetime on base of which the comment is added on them. It just like social website where we also seen the posts that are replied recently by someone and created recently by someone.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i suggest add 1 more field in posts table like updated_on, so when you create post make entry in updated_on same as added_on, now when someone comment then update date in updated on as well, change your query like:

```
SELECT id, title FROM posts ORDER BY updated_on DESC
```

Comment: Thanks for this, It's a great idea. But please help me in the query that I need to work on. Please

Comment: Also please write the query according to current logic.

Comment: You can use JOIN like:  SELECT id, title FROM posts as a LEFT JOIN post_replies as b ON a.id=b.post_id GROUP BY b.post_id ORDER BY updated_on DESC